# integer to [String]

Tags: list, haskell, show

with this code

```
digs 0 = []

digs x = x `mod` 1000 : digs (x `div` 1000)
```

for example: `24889375`
we take the result `[375,889,24]`

how can i make this one `["375","889","024"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Prelude> import Text.Printf
Prelude Text.Printf> map (printf "%03d" :: Int -> String) [375,889,24]
["375","889","024"]
```

Comment: @ifan: `map (printf "%03d" :: Int -> String) (digs 24889375)`.

Answer (score 2):

The most idiomatic way to do this is to use the functions `map` and `show`.

```
Prelude> map show [375,889,24]
["375","889","024"]
```

`show` can be used to convert most values to a string. `map` applies that function to every element of a list `map`.

Comment: that supplies ["375","889","24"] except 0